# acceder al hardware desde una app web mvc

Tags: mvc

tengo una libreria (dll) accede a un puerto COM (usb) qu econtrola un mecanismo.
el tema, es que cuando la uso desde una aplicacion tipo WindowsForm, puedo acceder a las instrucciones de la DLL sin problemas, es decir, funciona correctamente, pero cuando esta DLL la uso desde una aplicacion WEB MVC, se cae sin entregar ningun tipo de excepcion.
Lei por ahi, que desde las aplicaciones WEB, que se alojan en el IIS express en mi caso, hay que realizar ciertos cambios en la configuracion, ya que esto impide que se tenga acceso al hardware de la maquina. 
Alguien sabe algo de estas configuraciones? o que es necesario hacer para que esto funcione?
Saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Comment: al hardware de que maquina? del cliente?

Comment: hola, si, del cliente..  en este caso estoy ejecutando en VS2017

Comment: Creo que estas confundiendo como trabaja una pagina web. Tu dll, esta alojada en el servidor, a menos que se la baje el cliente, la instales y la ejecutes de alguna manera del lado del cliente. No tira ningun error, porque esta funcionando, pero en tu servidor.